# Row lock through EF to ensure order proccessing

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure-functions

I have a Azure Function App. It receives at lot of logs on a storage queue. Each log represents a row in a Azure Database that needs to be updated with status. As the function App is running a lot of instances simultaneously it can happen that two instances updates the same row but in wrong order. So I need to lock the specific row in the database, and if another instance tries to read it it has to wait for the row being released. By best bet is that row locking should do that. Can you achieve that with EF? Other suggestions are welcome too.

Notice it is not EF core, so needs to be supported with the standard version.

```
public static class ProccesLogQueue
{
    static SPOServiceConfiguration configuration = SPOServiceConfigurationManager.Get();

    [FunctionName("ProccesLogQueue")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("log", Connection = "AMRStorageConnStr")]string logJson, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {logJson}");

        var scanRepo = new ScanRepo(configuration.DBConnectionString);

        var json = JObject.Parse(logJson);
        var jobIdStr = json["JobId"].ToString();
        var evnt = json["Event"].ToString();
        var jobId = Guid.Parse(jobIdStr);

        // start lock the row
        var job = scanRepo.FindJob(jobId);

        if (job == null)
        {
            log.Info("Job not found");
            return;
        }

        if (job.Status == "JobEnd")
        {
            log.Info("Status allready JobEnd");
            return;
        }

        job.Status = evnt;
        job.Updated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        scanRepo.UpdateJob(job);
        // release the row

        log.Info(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the row with an UPDLOCK to prevent other instances from reading it until you commit the transaction.  Like this:

```
using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    //for ef core
    var job = db.Set<Job>().FromSqlInterpolated($"Select * from Jobs with (updlock) where JobId = {jobId}").First();

    //for ef6 or ef core
    //var job = db.Set<Job>().SqlQuery("Select * from Jobs with (updlock) where JobId = @jobId", jobId)

    job.Status = 4;

    db.SaveChanges();

    tran.Commit();
}
```

Comment: What version of EF you use? I dont have FromSqlInterpolated.

Comment: That's EF Core and it's an extension method in the namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql  See update for EF6 version.

Comment: Wouldn't updlock allow other instances to read it? Shouldn't it be rowlock instead?

Comment: Other sessions can read, but not with (updlock).  rowlock only changes the lock granularity.  With RCSI readers will be able to read regardless of the lock.  Readers without updlock shouldn't care whether they see the new or old status.